# Set Height of Grid according to content size

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, height

I have separate `Window`. It contains `Grid`. I need to set `Height` of this `Grid` according to content inside it.

In general this `Window` is like `Popup` so I want to show all content in it.

```
<Window x:Class="Stream.WPF.Popups.CustomMessageBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:Stream.WPF.Strings"
    Background="#7F000000" AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Grid Width="450" Background="#61596f">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="75" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFC0B6D1" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18" >
        <TextBlock Name="MessageTextBlock" Text="Unable to connect to the sensor. The program will now close.Unable to connect to the sensor. The program will now close.Unable to connect to the sensor. The program will now close.Unable to connect to the sensor. The program will now close.Unable to connect to the sensor. The program will now close." TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10 0"/>
   </TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="CloseBtn" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Content="{x:Static strings:Resource.CloseBtn}"  PreviewMouseUp="Cancel_Click" Foreground="#fff" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="14">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="bdr_main" Background="Transparent" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#c0b6d1" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" Margin="30,0,15,0">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdr_main" Property="Background" Value="#7FC0B6D1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

When `Text` of `TextBlock` is large - I want to make window also larger to show all text inside. But setting `Height` to `Auto` for `Grid` doesn't help, cause Grid's Height then is on all possible space, like height of window.

Setting `SizeToContent="Height"` to base `Window` also doesn't help, cause `Window` should be on all screen, and this property doesn't do this.

Comment: There's a static `Width` of `Grid` and static font size of `TextBlock` - the question is _where_ / _when_ you changing size of `TextBlock` ?

Comment: Try using "*" instead of "Auto" and give height parameter at Textblock Attribute

Comment: @Jasper, Well, I set `Width` because I want it as static. For Grid I didn't set Height, because I want it will be dynamic for content(it is especially about first row, where I also set height like Auto). Cause TextBlock has property `TextWrapping="Wrap"` it will show text inside available space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Grid's `VerticalAlignment` as `Center`.